# Issue in setting spring configuration for using thymeleaf template based mail?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a multi module project. I want to use thymeleaf email templates in project and this needs to be done in the service module for webservices. So i configured the common-xml as:

```
     <bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="mail/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <!-- Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    templates to be automatically updated when modified.    -->    
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="templateEngineCustom" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

This setting is unable to solve the thymeleaf template using TemplateEngine. How can I use templates in thymeleaf-spring mail configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solves the problem when i use **org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine** instead of **org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine** as:

```
<bean id="templateEngineCustom" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolvers">
     <set>
         <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
     </set>
 </property>
</bean>
```